# How to define Xpath for element inside Shadow root

Tags: xpath, shadow-dom

I can follow this doc https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors/#xpath to define locator by using CSS selector and it works.
Just need to add ">>>" as prefix.
But i am failed to find the same solution for Xpath.

Has anyone know about that?